# What is the best practice in signing assemblies that have private accessor

Tags: visual-studio-2010, assembly-signing

I have a project that should be signed. This project is set with InternalVisibleTo attribute to my Test project. The test project refers to private accessors that throw an exception: accessors hasn't strong name.
Now, how, for God's sake, I suppose to sign the assembly!
Should I sign only project without tests doing some refactoring or is there workaround with private accessors?
What would be the best practice?
Thank you in advance.